# Share a simple text on the twitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I am working on sharing functionality and I want to share some simple text on Twitter. I know that we use both Compose and Account Twitter functionality, which is registered in setting. I found a sample that shares media, but I have no media: just simple text. Can anyone help me find the request URL needed to share simple text?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shareit.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7);
NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = @"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json"; // (This url is used to share media, but I want text rather than an image.)
NSDictionary *params = @{@"media" : imageData}; // **** (Don't know the parameter for share text)
NSError *clientError;
NSURLRequest *request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] 
                         URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                         URL:statusesShowEndpoint
                         parameters:params
                         error:&clientError];

if (request) {
    [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
     sendTwitterRequest:request
     completion:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                  NSData *data,
                  NSError *connectionError) {
         if (data) {
             // handle the response data e.g.
             NSError *jsonError;
             NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                   JSONObjectWithData:data
                                   options:0
                                   error:&jsonError];
             NSLog(@"%@",json);
         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", connectionError);
         }
     }];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);
}
```

I want two things:

1. request URL
2. parameter for sharing

Comment: see https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/TwitterPost

Comment: @KiritModi Thanks for quick answer but i am not find anything for share simple text. It is good if you give me more specified answer

Comment: @KiritModi i find the solution from your demo. Can you please post the answer so i can accept it and other can also find the solution

Comment: you welcome and happy coding @KiritModi ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all download the class of [FHSTwitterEngine](http://ge.tt/5fwbxKM2/v/0)

after check user is login in twitter or not, if user doen't login then ask about login. on tweet button.

```
-(IBAction)tweet:(id)sender
{
    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SavedAccessHTTPBody"] length] > 0)
    {
        [self TwitterStatus];
    }
    else
    {
        UIViewController *loginController = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loginControllerWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

            if (success)
            {
                NSLog(@"== %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SavedAccessHTTPBody"]);

                [self TwitterStatus];
            }

            NSLog(success?@"L0L success":@"O noes!!! Loggen faylur!!!");

            // NSLog(@"Sucess = %d",[success integervalue]);
        }];
        [self presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Now if user is already login then `TwitterStatus` called and tweet on your account as below method.

```
-(void)TwitterStatus
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSString *tweet = @"This is testing message with image.";

            NSData *data=UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"scan.png"]);
            NSError *returned = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]postTweet:tweet withImageData:data];

            NSLog(@"== %@",returned);

            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

            NSString *title = nil;
            NSString *message = nil;

            if ([returned isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
                NSError *error = (NSError *)returned;
                title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %ld",(long)error.code];
                message = error.localizedDescription;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"%@",returned);
                title = @"Tweet Posted";
                message = tweet;
            }

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                @autoreleasepool {
                    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [av show];
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

You can also reply, favorite and retweet [Refer](https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/TwitterPost)